# Given a set $A$ of size $n$, is there a formula for the number of anti-reflexive relations on $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

By anti reflexive I mean: $\forall (a \in A)$, $\neg (aRa)$
Given a set $A$ of size $n$, is there a formula for the number of anti-reflexive relations on $A$?

Comment: What you’ve defined there is *antisymmetry*, not anti-reflexivity.

Comment: The term for this is *antisymmetric*. "Anti-reflexive" would (probably) mean that the relation is *strict*: for all $a\in A$, not $aRa$.

Comment: It's too late I'm sorry. I meant what you wrote and I edited my question

Comment: For every ordered pair $(a,b)$ of distinct elements, we have two choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anti-reflexive relations on $A$ are precisely the subsets of $(A\times A)\setminus D$, where $D=\{\langle a,a\rangle:a\in A\}$ is the diagonal of $A\times A$. $|A\times A|=n^2$, and $|D|=n$, so $|(A\times A)\setminus D|=n^2-n=n(n-1)$.

How many subsets does a set of cardinality $n^2-n$ have? I’ve added the answer in the spoiler-protected block below, but take a crack at it yourself before you check.

> Each element of the set is either in or out of any given subset, so in forming a subset of $(A\times A)\setminus D$ we’re making a two-way choice — include the element in the subset of not — a total of $n^2-n$ times. By the multiplication principle there are $2^{n^2-n}$ ways to do this.